# How can I remove a project from the sidebar?

Tags: qt-creator

New to Qt Creator. I just want to clean up the sidebar so it only shows the current project. How can I remove (not delete) my other projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click on the project folder and select "close project".